# Restrict access to cube based on role in SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, security, ssas

I have two cubes under one SSAS database that I am building. Essentially, they're the same except one cube contains a dimension with confidential data and one does not contain that dimension.

What I'm looking to do is restrict access to the cube containing confidential data to a limited set of users, but it seems that SSAS roles are only at the database level and not the cube level?

Is there a way I can set up security at the cube level in SSAS, so some users can see both cubes when they open it in Excel, and other users can only see one cube?

Comment: Grant read access to one cube and not the other. There is a cubes tab in the role designer.

Answer (score 0):

Greg meant to grant it here:

[image: SSAS_Role]

Just leave "None" access level for certain cube.